# ScrollView Won't Scroll - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollview

I'm new to iOS development and Xcode and am trying to learn. First off, I know there are many posts on this very thing and I would not post unless I was desperate. I have quadruple checked all my constraints after reading many posts, videos and articles. I cannot get my scrollview to scroll. I have included all relevant screenshots but if you need more information I can provide. I am doing all this via storyboard rather than programmatically and would prefer to continue in this manner. Please excuse the repeated horizontal constraints in image 4. They are just a repeat and not duplicate constraints. Thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I see similar. After the latest xcode update, scrollview operations don't work how they used to. Hopefully someone has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement a scroll view is very easy here are the steps:

1. set up a stackView or regular view and input everything you want to be inside that view/stackview (buttons, labels, etc...) -> this is called your "Contentview"
2. Click on your ContentView and hit "embed in scroll view"

[image: embed button]

3. Click on the scroll view and give it constraints (if you want it to be the full screen -> hit 0 an all 4 sides

[image: constraints window]

4. Open the side panel and click on the scroll view

[image: side panel]

5. Now ctr-drag the ContentView to the Frame-layout-Guide and hit "equal widths" if you want it to scroll up and down (if you want it to scroll left/right -> hit "equal Heights")

[image: scroll view vs contentview]

6. Now ctrl-drag the ContentView to the Content-Layout-Guide and hit
   "top",   "leading",   "trailing",  &  "bottom space to content layout guide"
7. It should be working, if it looks weird, click on the Content-Layout-Guide and go to the size inspector. then make sure that all the constraints are set to 0

[image: size inspector]

@seanPatterson also you have have the view as "freeform", you want it to be "inferred"